# Java Firebase Firestore how to set json field alias

Tags: java, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to set a json alias for a field when converting a DocumentSnapshot to an object?

```
package com.example;

public class Customer {
    private String id;
    private String email;
    // @JsonAlias("name") // How I would do it if I was using Jackson
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userID;

    ... getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about provide a factory method to create a Customer object as below:

```
// Private constructor to enforce factory method usage
private Customer() {}

public static Customer fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
    customer.setEmail(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
    customer.setFirstName(documentSnapshot.getString("name")); // Alias for firstName
    customer.setLastName(documentSnapshot.getString("lastName"));
    customer.setUserID(documentSnapshot.getString("userID"));

    return customer;
}
// Getters & setters
```

Then you can use it like :

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = // Retrieve document from Firestore
Customer customer = Customer.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot);
```